# Webmin stopped working after upgrade to Stretch

Tags: debian, perl, webmin

After upgrading to Stretch, upon trying to enter `webmin` via the `www`, it gives an error instead:

```
Error - Perl execution failed

Can't locate WebminCore.pm in @INC (you may need to install the WebminCore module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl/5.24.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl5/5.24 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl/5.24 /usr/share/perl/5.24 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl-base ..) at /usr/share/webmin/blue-theme/index.cgi line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/webmin/blue-theme/index.cgi line 4.
```

Tried to add `PERLLIB=/usr/share/webmin` to `~root/.profile`, it did not work.

Interestingly enough, when calling the `webmin` perl binary from the command line, it does not seem to throw any error.

What is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that in Stretch, there is a need for an extra PERL library PATH.

Upon inspection of the `webmin` perl code, I found out a configure directive `perllib`is accepted in the configuration file; and the code adds it to whatever is already configured in `PERLLIB` for the duration of the program.

```
24 %config = &read_config_file($config_file);
25 if ($config{'perllib'}) {
26         push(@INC, split(/:/, $config{'perllib'}));
27         $ENV{'PERLLIB'} .= ':'.$config{'perllib'};
28         }
```

So, I added to the file `/etc/webmin/miniserv.conf` the line:

```
perllib=/usr/share/webmin
```

And `webmin` started working.

P.S. If you arrived here due to problems in Webmin after migrating to Stretch see also [Webmin stopped opening](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331979/webmin-stopped-opening/331980)