# Dovecot rejecting client certificate

Tags: email, ssl, dovecot, thunderbird, imap

I have configured dovecot to use Client certificate authentication. I have used CA.pl (openssl wrapper) to create CA cert and sign client and server certs with that.(no certificate chain, CA cert is trusted in client) I have set the certificate as CA certificate in dovecot for client auth. Dovecot correctly asks IceDove for certificates but after clicking OK, It fails with error 
"Client didn't present valid SSL certificate."

Using openssl to manually test IMAP connection also results in this error.

dovecot config: https://gist.github.com/Xcess/71f7eeeda0a270b252f1de5d7308c0e2

I have tried certificate with CN=user1 and CN=user1@domain.com. both failed. Also set common-name to be username in dovecot conf...no difference.

I don't know what to do as this is all stated in manuals and seems pretty simple and straightforward. But it fails.

thanks

---

Update 1:
output of command `openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout`:

> Certificate:
>       Data:
>           Version: 3 (0x2)
>           Serial Number:
>               8e:3d:9b:7c:13:35:88:b7
>       Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
>           Issuer: C=IR, ST=Isf, O=Apps4you, CN=lnxsrv2
>           Validity
>               Not Before: Mar  1 10:45:32 2017 GMT
>               Not After : Mar  1 10:45:32 2018 GMT
>           Subject: C=AU, ST=Some-State, O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, CN=user1/emailAddress=user1@apps4you.com
>           Subject Public Key Info:
>               Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
>                   Public-Key: (2048 bit)
>                   Modulus:
>                      ---
>                   Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
>           X509v3 extensions:
>               X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
>                   CA:FALSE
>               Netscape Comment: 
>                   OpenSSL Generated Certificate
>               X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: ---
>   -----Output ommited-----

---

Update 2:
this slightly modified config file also doesn't work:
https://gist.github.com/Xcess/599beaec17a4a524a2acbde1b7f5c70f

---

Update 3:
Verbose SSL Log file :
https://gist.github.com/Xcess/f54850ecdaa6bcd044a77d133cb9b9c2

Comment: X.509 can be a complicated theme for someone not familiar with it. For starters, nowadays most of the modern OS/browsers are starting to refuse certificates with a key smaller than 2048 bits. see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331979/webmin-stopped-opening

Comment: I advise you to add the output of `openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout` to the post. Edit the relevant bits to take out private information.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I added the output. Thanks. btw, this is a server error and client is not rejecting anything.

Comment: I assume that is the client certificate. I am not seeing any X.509 extensions/ OIDs about being a certificate used for client authentication, hence the error... do you have any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer so I thought I should post it here too. (precisely [@behrad-eslamifar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/196366/behrad-eslamifar) did :)

you should append the CRL to the CA certificate given to dovecot **EVEN IF YOU HAVE SET ssl_require_crl = no**

like this way :

```
openssl ca -gencrl -out crlfile
cat crlfile >> cacert.pem
service dovecot restart
```

thanks everyone for their suggestions. <3

Comment: Together with the bits about being client, no? Pretty interesting nonetheless,  it may be worth filing a bug with the dovecot guys.

Comment: cert type etc you mean? yes I changed those with no result. I've tried everything... :/ I agree It's worth filling a bug. Do so if you can please...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a X.509 Extension to this cert to use it for client authentication.

In `openssl.cnf`, under `[ usr_cert ]`, per the `openssl.conf` example:

```
[ usr_cert ]
nsCertType = client, email
```

However, supposedly the nsCertType is obsolete, and it is required to also add a X.509 extension. Add then a new section:

```
[ xpclient_ext]
extendedKeyUsage = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2
```

To add the extension, you will also need to pass the option `-extensions xpclient_ext` to openssl when generating the certificate.

> The following extended key usage purposes are defined by RFC 3280:
>
> serverAuth (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1) -- TLS Web server authentication
>   clientAuth (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2) -- TLS Web client authentication

Please do note that I advise to both add the `nsCertType` and the RFC 3280 extension. Some software, notably PfSense, still check for `nsCertType`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry for replying late. I'm going to test it today and report back the result. However I should say that the same certificate worked fine for NginX client certificate authentication.

Comment: I set both options you said, and created a keypair with openssl command. the I signed it with CA.pl like usual. then converted to pkcs12 then imported into system and icedove. Still same error :(

Comment: what errors have you in the log files?

Comment: Please also add to the question the cert on the server side.

Comment: log added @rui-f-ribeiro . you mean the CA or server cert? both are working fine by themselves. before client certificate everything was ok and also CA works fine.

Comment: If you want both nsType and EKU, which I agree is safest, they must be in the same `[section]` because only one extensions section is used per signing operation (`ca` or `x509 -CA*` or `req -x509`). And OpenSSL knows pkix names so you can use `extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth`